# Accessing the state inside the function that is used to set the state

Tags: react-native

I wanted to access the updated value of the state inside the function which I have used to update the state.

```
const [test , setTest] = useState("old val");

const run = () => {
    setTest("new val");
    console.log(test);
}
```

this is giving me the old value of test i.e. "old val". How do I access the new val that is set to set inside the function `run`.

I have gone through several StackOverflow questions for this. I found 1 common solution everywhere which did the following :

```
setTest("new val" , () => {
 console.log(test);
})
```

But when I did this, I didn't get the desired result but got a warning instead which said `useState() hooks do not take the second parameter callback arg.`

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing this problem because `useState` hook is asynchronous.
There are 2 solutions to this:
Use async/await

```
const run = async () => {
    await setTest("new val");
    console.log(test);
}
```

You can also use the `useEffect` hook to access the latest state update, I reccomend to use this approach to trigger your action when test value change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(test);
  // Do whatever you want with the new value here
}, [test]);
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot to move forward.